# How can I relate two entities with ManyToOne?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, many-to-one

In my `pages` entity, I added icon via "ManyToOne":

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Icons", inversedBy="pages")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $icon;


  public function getIcon(): ?Icons
{
    return $this->icon;
}

public function setIcon(?Icons $icon): self
{
    $this->icon = $icon;
    return $this;
}
```

But I have problem with this, I get an error message:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1,
>   t0.unique_id AS unique_id_2, t0.name AS name_3, t0.template AS
>   template_4, t0.slug AS slug_5, t0.icon_id AS icon_id_6 FROM pages t0
>   WHERE t0.slug = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["pages"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.icon_id' in
>   'field list'

Comment: Did you update your database schema after adding new column to entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine will search for column named `[relationed_one]_id` on `relation_many` table.
If the relationship of Icon and Page is made by another foreign key that icon_id on pages table you can indicate with `@JoinColumn(name="another_foreign_id", referencedColumnName="another_primary_id")`

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional